# A "natural"/simple strictly concave function on $[0, \infty)$ that's smooth, positive everywhere, unbounded above, and has a bounded derivative

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to apply a concave transformation to some data I have and am using in a Bayesian analysis. In this context, I think I want a function that is:

1. Defined on $[0, \infty)$
2. Smooth i.e. infinitely differentiable
3. Strictly concave
4. Positive everywhere
5. Unbounded above i.e. $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$
6. $f(0) = 0$
7. Has a finite first derivative everywhere

$\log(x)$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are pretty standard concave transforms that satisfy 1–6 but $\lim_{x \to 0^+}$ of the derivative of each is $\infty$.

I believe $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} \tanh(x)) + x$ (pictured below) satisfies all these criteria, but it feels a little artificial. Is there some standard or simpler concave transformation like this that I'm just not thinking of? Or just other alternative functions that also satisfy the criteria? (Obviously I can swap $\arctan$ and other sigmoid functions in for $\tanh$.) It doesn't seem like my requirements are that esoteric.

[image: The equation]

Comment: If the issue is the limit as $x \to 0+$, you could translate the graph to the left. Take $\sqrt{x + 1}$ or $\log(1 + x)$ (note that the latter satisfies point 4, unlike $\log x$). Are these sufficiently natural? Your example doesn't strike me as that artificial either, so it would be good to get a better idea of where that line is.

Comment: (Sorry, for point 6, you should use $\sqrt{x + 1} - 1$ instead of $\sqrt{x + 1}$.)

Comment: Yeah, those are both reasonable candidates too. Thanks! I guess I'm partly just a little surprised that there isn't (at least that I know of or can find) a standard approach here given that the the $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x)= \infty$ seems annoying in many contexts.

Comment: Yeah, no worries on point 6. I added that after the fact and that's an easy adjustment to make.

Comment: $f(x)=\ln(x+1)$ for all $x \geq 0$. I can't think of a more natural than that.